# ¿Como puedo llamar a una función al recibir un correo nuevo en Gmail con AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Tengo un Script que necesito que se dispare cada vez que recibo un correo electrónico en mi bandeja de entrada de Gmail, sin embargo, no se como hacerlo.

El Script lo cree desde el Drive, porque desde Gmail no encuentro la forma.
¿Alguien sabe cómo se hace?

Comment: Hola Catalina, bienvenida a SOes, nos gustaría ayudarte y para lograrlo nos podrías dar mayores detalles por favor? Qué hace el script? Qué deseas lograr? Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Para ello necesitas crear un trigger que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, por ejemplo cada 5 minutos y leer los mails recibidos, y por ejemplo si encuentra alguna palabra clave ejecutar alguna acción, con un código similar a este :

```
function doSomething(){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("My Action");  
  if(label == null){
    GmailApp.createLabel('My Action');
  }
  else{
    var threads = label.getThreads();  
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {  
      var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      var from = message.getFrom();
      var subject = message.getSubject();
      // do something
    }
    label.removeFromThreads(threads);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script (GAS) no tiene eventos para el servicio Gmail por medio del cual se pueda llamar una función al recibir un nuevo correo.

Dependiendo de cómo manejes tu casilla de correo y lo que quieras hacer al recibir un nuevo correo podría serte de utilidad un disparador dirigido por tiempo (time-driven trigger). Por ejemplo, si aplicas un enfoque de Ningún mensaje en la bandeja de entrada (Zero inbox) podrías usar `GmailApp.getInboxThreads()` para obtener todos los mensajes que estén pendientes de ser procesados.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien han dicho los compañeros no existe un evento de google que te diga que has recibido un correo. Ha de ser tu script el que activamente busque los correos nuevos.

Un código como este:

```
function ReplyEmail()
{
  var emails = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

  for(var e = 0 ; e < emails.length ; ++e )
  {
     var email = emails[e];

     if ( email.isInInbox() && email.isUnread() )
     {
       var string = email.getMessages()[0].getFrom();
        if ( string.match( "jose") )
       {
            email.reply("Mensaje Respondido Automaticamente: Jose, ahora     mismo estamos de vacaciones, en cuanto podamos tendremos en cuenta su petición");
           email.markRead();
       }
     }
  }
}
```

...Que tendrás que hacer que se ejecute cada cuanto necesites. Te recomiendo que no lo ejecutes muy seguido, depende de la cantidad de correos que tengas y de lo que hagas en el script te podrías quedar sin cuota de ejecución.

Referencias:

[Como responder emails automaticamente](http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2015/11/como-responder-emails-de-forma.html)

[Como leer emails con gas](http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2015/11/como-leer-mensajes-de-gmail-desde.html)

[Como ejecutar scripts automáticamente](http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2015/11/como-ejecutar-automaticamente-scripts.html)